# Как хранить и загружать фрагменты в Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Собрал Navigation Drawer по [этому](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) тюториалу. Изменил фрагменты на свои, в которых происходит парсинг с помощью `Jsoup` в `Asynctask`. Мне бы хотелось сохранить каждый фрагмент при первом открытии через `Navigation Drawer` и далее уже загружать из памяти, чтобы парсинг происходил единожды, а не при каждом открытии фрагмента.

Пробовал загружать фрагменты по алгоритму ниже, ничего хорошего из этого не выходит, парсинг происходит при каждом открытии фрагмента.

```
private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_BASIC);
            if(fragment == null){
                return new HomeFragment();
            }else{
                return fragment;
            }
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
...
```

Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Уточните в чем собственно проблема. `findFragmentByTag()` ничего не находит?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja именно. Количество фрагментов статичное. Заменяю фрагменты этим способом:  `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeHolder, fragment, CURRENT_TAG); fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();`

Comment: А в каком методе фрагмента у вас загрузка данных? Посмотрите на жизненный цикл фрагмента. Когда и какие методы вызываются. Может стоит делать внешний запрос, а в фрагмент передавать данные? Или делать его в конструкторе. Правда если для запроса нужен контекст, то создайте класс обращения к нему. Если заинтересовало, могу объяснить развернуто.

Comment: @Игорь Парсинг запускается в конструкторе адаптера. Но вашу идею я вроде уловил. Надеюсь, проблем не возникнет, если буду запускать `Asynctask` в `MainActivity` и передавать данные во фрагмент, далее буду хранить эти данные в `MainActivity`, я правильно вас понял? Буду благодарен за развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Концептуально правильным решением будет загруженные и распаршенные данные складировать в БД и оттуда их доставать и отображать. При чём делать это лучше всего в `Presenter` - т.е. надо `MVP` применить. После этого можно всё это, при желании, ускорить (в смысле отрисовки) не заменяя фрагменты, но скрывая/показывая их (`show`/`hide` вместо `replace`).

Но всё это, конечно, долго и сложно. И не факт, что поможет, особенно, если вы парсинг запускаете в `onResume` фрагментов.

Comment: Такая мысль имеется, загружать в БД и доставать оттуда, но отсеивалась по причине изнурительной работы. В любом случае, сделаю именно так, если не найду иной выход. Парсинг запускается в адаптере фрагмента.

Answer (score 0):

Получается, у вас запрос идет из конструктора фрагмента, и каждый раз при его отображении этот запрос повторяется. Это значит что фрагмент пересоздается. Что бы этого избежать, создайте свои фрагменты как поля класса, а в своем методе их проверку:

```
 private PhotosFragment photosFragment;
 private HomeFragment homeFragment;

 private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
      case 0:
        // home
        if(homeFragment == null)homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        return homeFragment;

    case 1:
        // photos
        if(photosFragment==null)photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
         return photosFragment;

        }
```

Если решите делать запрос из MainActivitY. То данные во фрагмент передавайте через Bundle.

```
     private Fragment addBundle(Fragment fragment){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("TAG",str);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
        }
```

А в самом фрагменте в onCreteView()

```
       Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
       if(bundle!=null){
       str = bundle.getString("TAG");
       }
```

Можно конечно сеттером, но это не так надежно. Хотя, если это фотографии то все не так просто, насколько я помню в транзакции Bundle ограничение на 1мб, по этому остается сеттер. А хранить их в памяти не советую, может упасть приложение. По хорошему вам надо использовать внешнюю библиотеку типа Glide или Picasso, ну или самому делать обработку изображений и их кешировать.